# Why this "this" behavior?

Tags: javascript, this

Hello I am stuck on a case I don't get

here is the code

```
function car(speed) {
    this.speed = speed; 
    this.accelerate = function() {
        this.speed += 1;
    }
}

var oldcar = new car(1);

function test(cb){
  cb();
}

test(oldcar.accelerate);

console.log(oldcar.speed);
// 1

test(function(){ oldcar.accelerate(); });

console.log(oldcar.speed);
// 2
```

On the first function call test(), I observe that the **this** in the oldcar.accelerate method is set to window.

On the second case, the **this** is correctly set to oldcar.

I don't understand how calling test() with oldcar.accelerate instead of function(){ oldcar.accelerate(); } make such a difference.

Can someone explain the behavior ? thanks !

Comment: Because that's how `this` is meant to be: it's meaning depends on how you call the function.

Comment: [Comprehensive related Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: because `thisParticularObjectReference.fn(arg)` is equivalent to `thisParticularObjectReference.fn.call(thisParticularObjectReference, arg)`, whereas using a reference to the function to call it `var fn = obj.fn; fn(arg)` is equivalent to `fn.call(undefined, arg)` wich sets `this` to the global object *(without 'use strict')*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you pass a method as a callback you are passing only the method, not the object which it belongs to.

When `this` is used in without any given scope, it defaults to `window` (or the closest surrounding scope).

A correct way is to pass the entire object, or an anonymous function has has access to the entire object..

```
function test(cb){
  cb();
}

test(function(){ oldcar.accelerate() });
```

Comment: An equally correct way would be to pass it an anonymous function, then in that call your object method. That way `test` doesn't care what it receives, so long as its a method.

Comment: AHH ok your answer make complete sence with the comment of thomas. "thisParticularObjectReference.fn(arg) is equivalent to thisParticularObjectReference.fn.call(thisParticularObjectRe‌​ference, arg)"

Comment: think about it like this.. if i wanted to slap you i wouldn't cut my arm off and mail it to you, my arm wouldn't know what to do when it arrives. the only way i can slap you is to send my whole self to you :)